# Heroku Node.js sample facebook app does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, heroku, express

The Heroku app i'm trying to get to work (code here):
https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs

"Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL" errors occur when the page is loaded in chrome.

The login button takes you to facebook but does not actually log you into the app and gives the same errors.

Has anyone got this app to work on Chrome or can anyone advise as to how to patch it up?

P.S. it seems to work fine on Mozilla.

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: sorry just added a link to the code. its here https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs

Comment: This is probably a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain this is a cross domain policy issue, as stated above. Generally speaking, you just need to add the correct header info to the response.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

In Node, I think it is just a matter of adding it as another header in the response, using

> response.writeHead

See http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers

Oh, and there's explicit instructions on how to do it if you're using Express. I see no reason why it can't work using plain old node then.

http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

So I looked at your link, in your case I think you just have to enter the header info prior to using any other express app methods.

As to why it works in Firefox and not Chrome, not sure. Both support CORS many versions back. Maybe you have some Chrome extension that's interfering.